# 4-D lattices and quaternions

Tags: abstract-algebra, quaternions, division-algebras

It is easy to prove that there are only 2 extensions $\mathbb{Q}(a)$, with $|a|=1$, of $\mathbb{Q}$ where $\mathbb{Z}[a]$ becomes a lattice(discrete free abelian subgroup of rank 2) in the complex plane: $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[e^{2\pi i/3}]$. Can I generalize this fact to the quaternionic(?) extension of $\mathbb{Q}$? That is,

how many (up to conjugacy?) division algebras $D$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ are there, with:

(i) $D\subset \mathbb{H}$, where $\mathbb{H}$ is the quaternion skew-field,

(ii) $D$ is a 4-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ containing $\mathbb{Q}$,

(iii) for some unital(norm 1) base $B=\{1,a,b,c\}$ of $D$, the span $B\mathbb{Z}$ forms a 4-dim lattice,

(iv) $B$ in (iii) satisfies that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $a^n,b^n,c^n\in B\mathbb{Z}$?

I cannot be completely convinced that the problem is well-posed, but I guess the point seems clear.

Comment: IIRC: There are infinitely many non-isomorphic 4-dimensional division algebras $D$ with center $\Bbb{Q}$. We can classify them according to how they behave at each prime number (including "a prime at infinity"). The algebra $D$ is contained in $\Bbb{H}$ iff it behaves in a certain way at the infinite priime. Each and every one of the algebras $D$ has so called *(maximal) orders* $\mathcal{O}$. They are rank 4 free abelian subgroups that are also rings (=contain $1_D$ and are closed under multiplication). So any order works in the role of $B\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: Unfortunately explaining all of the above in any kind of detail might fill, if not a book at least a sheaf of notes. Would a set of highlighted examples be ok as an answer? You were interested in lattices. In that case I lead off by mentioning [the ring of Icosians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosian).

Comment: Thanks, sorry for late check. I found some textbooks on orders by googling, so I guess I can deal with the problem by myself.

Comment: No problem. Saved me the headache of deciding what to include in an answer. Reiner's *Maximal Orders* is comprehensive, but may be too much - depending on your background.